# Get checked or not checked multi value checkbox

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Hi everyone I have a form with 5 checkboxes, once I run the post I would like to have all the checkboxes with the current status.

Example:

checkbox 1: on
checkbox 2: off
checbox 3: on
checkbox 4: off
checkbox 5: off

This is my code but it doesn't work with non-on states

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $array = $_POST["check_list"];
    }

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"><label>Mon</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"><label>Tue</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"><label>Wed</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"><label>Thu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"><label>Fri</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

How can I get all the checkboxes with the statuses sent in the post?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value keyword can be used to specify the value:

### Hardcoded Values

```
$days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $array = $_POST["check_list"];

    foreach ($days as $day){
        $isChecked = in_array($day, $array);
        echo $day . ' is ' . ($isChecked ? ' checked' : ' not checked') . '<br />';
    }
}


?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    foreach ($days as $day){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' .$day.'"><label>'.$day.'</label>';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

### Dynamic Values

If the fields get added dynamically, hidden inputs can be used. The following snippet adds a hidden input for every available option. These hidden inputs can then be used to determine if there is an associated checkbox, and thus get the value.

Checkout the following example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $options = $_POST["check_list_options"];
    $checkedValues = $_POST["check_list_values"];

    foreach ($options as $optionId){
        $isChecked = array_key_exists($optionId, $checkedValues);

        if($isChecked){
            echo 'option ' . $optionId . ' is checked and has value: '.$checkedValues[$optionId].'<br />';
        }else{
            echo 'option ' . $optionId . ' is not checked<br />';
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" id="checklist_form" method="post">
    <div class="results">

    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add_days">
        Add days
    </button>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    var addDays = document.querySelector('#add_days');
    var form = document.querySelector('#checklist_form');
    var results = document.querySelector('.results');

    addDays.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var inputId = document.querySelectorAll('.input').length;

        results.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="check_list_options[]" value="'+inputId+'" />' +
            '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list_values['+inputId+']" value="mon'+inputId+'" class="input" />' +
            '<label>Day '+inputId+'</label>' +
            '<br />';
    })
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is that with a button I add another list composed of those 5 checkboxes

Comment: Added an example for dynamic form elements! @MarkZhiu

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving a name to each checkbox or by adding the key to the name of checkbox, and create an array that contains the name of each checkbox, then check in a loop if the equivalent checkbox is set:

```
    $checkboxes = ['checkbox 1', 'checkbox 2', 'checkbox 3', 'checkbox 4', 'checkbox 5'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach($checkboxes as $key=>$value) {

                echo $value.': ';
                if(isset($_POST["check_list"][$key])) echo 'on '; else echo 'off ';
            }
    }

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[0]"><label>Mon</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[1]"><label>Tue</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[2]"><label>Wed</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[3]"><label>Thu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[4]"><label>Fri</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```